# Syntax for populating a DataGridView containing per-item BindingList data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I am working on a project that requires pre-populating a DataGridView control (C#/Visual Studio/WinForms). Getting the sample data in correctly is proving to be a bit tricky.

Here is a sample item:

```
Inventory.Products.Add(new Product(11, "Sledgehammer", 15, 11, 1, 25, new BindingList<Part>()));
```

Everything populates correctly, and it adds the empty per-item BindingList (which will later indicate the parts that the product is made of). What I'm trying to do is *pre-populate* all of the parts for each product, instead of just the empty BindingList.

The BindingList that it is referencing is called AssociatedParts and is pulling from a Part class that pulls PartIDs, etc.

```
public BindingList<Part> AssociatedParts = new BindingList<Part>();
```

More specifically, I'm trying to pass PartIDs (from my basic Part Class that the BindingList is referencing) so that I can define what parts go with what product in the pre-populated Demo/Nonsense data.

I have been looking everywhere can cannot find the correct formatting for this. Any pointers would be much-appreciated by this C# newbie.

Comment: What is `Inventory.Products`? Where is the data coming from? Are you using Entity Framework? How are you loading it? Please post more context.

Comment: Inventory.Products is just a simple class that has some demo fields for each product, like ProductID, Price, InStock, etc. There is no real datasource or database. Not using Entity Framework. The only data is about 25 lines of manually pre-populated items  just like the example I posted. The idea is just to have some sample products to play around with. All I'm trying to find is the syntax for referencing the items within a BindingList.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As Dai said, please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your problem to let the members see, what is going wrong and how to help you. Please have a look at the Help Center how to ask.